# How to fix that macOS version is 10.11 but CoreData NSFetchRequest<ResultType> support for 10.12 and above

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchrequest

I am working on `macOS` app and I am using `CoreData` for storing in database. App will give support from `OS X 10.11` and above. In `OS X 10.12` machine app working fine, but `OS X 10.11` it is not working before I call the  database storage method that things update in UI like set label text like that. After that CoreData method called, UI also not updating. I figure out because of below code

```
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Entity> = Entity.fetchRequest()

do {
   let  dbDisc = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Entity]        
}
```

please tell me what is the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, I use this code to check the current version:

```
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {}
```

For MacOS, I think it could be the same syntax. See this [post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking)

Comment: I tried this also not working. I am sure that problem with NSFetchRequestResult (available 10.12+). So I tried let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cart") but it thrown issue like "generic method could not be inferred" and it forced to change as "let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Entity> = Entity.fetchRequest()". Don't know how to resolve